# Windows Phone 8.0 Facebook/Twitter/Google + Sharing?

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to share image on facebook , twitter and google + using windows phone 8.0(silverlight) app development?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762118/how-to-share-picture-on-facebook-from-my-windows-phone-app

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will definitely help you

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
cameraCaptureTask.Show();

       void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
       {
            if(e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
           {
               ShowShareMediaTask(e.OriginalFileName);
           }
       }
       void ShowShareMediaTask(string path)
       {
           ShareMediaTask shareMediaTask = new ShareMediaTask();
           shareMediaTask.FilePath = path;
           shareMediaTask.Show();
       }
```

Take the help of the following link for further reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207027%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: Hi Jaffer , when i am using share media task , i cannot see option of facebook , twitter and other apps. It only gives me option to share through outlook.What could be the issue ?

Comment: So, you need code for sharing with the help of social media, right.If this is the case then let me know I will try for something else...ok

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post direct on the social network, you can uses the deep link.

Facebook: https://somoswindev.wordpress.com/2015/06/09/postando-diretamente-no-facebook-usando-c-no-windows-phone/

Twitter: https://somoswindev.wordpress.com/2015/06/01/postanto-no-twitter-no-windows-phone-usando-c/